# Callbacks not getting fired for simple interactions in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, angularjs

We're trying to listen for the PinchZoom interaction but we're not getting nothing in the callback.

**Creating the map**

```
this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2,
      }),
    });
```

**Listening for pinch interactions**

```
const mapInteraction = new PinchZoom();
mapInteraction.on('change:active', (event) => {
      console.log('event', event);
    });
this.map.addInteraction(mapInteraction);
```

I've tried with MouseWheelZoom event also, but the same issue occurs there too. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of these "on" functions?

Here's a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular10-openlayers-demo-41up43)

Comment: `change:active` is fired when the setActive() method is used to enable or disable an interaction.  It is not related to user activity.